# Get Custom Attributes values from a .kml file using google map api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I am using google map API to display .kml file  as map.I want to get all elements value that we assigned into the .kml file as an alert. I am trying the following way ,

```
  kmlLayer.addListener('click', function(event) {

      alert(event.featureData.pid); 
      map.setCenter(event.latLng);
      map.setZoom(20);   
      var content = event.featureData.infoWindowHtml;
      var testimonial = document.getElementById('capture');
      testimonial.innerHTML = content;
       $('#myModal').modal('show');

    });
```

But i am getting the alert as "Undefined" . Here pid is the element which i specified in that .kml file. That means ,

```
<Placemark id="ID_00000">
 **<pid>2</pid>**
 <name>PARK</name>
 <description>This is Sample Description</description>
 <coordinates> ..... </coordinates> .......
```

Please help me to solve  this issues.

Comment: KmlLayer won't give you access to those.  You need to parse the KML (or use a third party KML parser)

Comment: i am also try in geoxml3 but i cannot get the proper result